# How can I edit Google Colab notebooks in real-time with others?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I would like to use Google Colab for real-time editing like in Google Sheets, where it's possible to see what other people are doing instantly. I'd like to know if this is possible also on Google Colab by doing some configuration, because I'm trying to edit one code with my friend, but our changes don't show to each other.
His changes only show after several seconds, and the pages automatically go to the top when it occurs.

Comment: Sorry Pedro, but opinion-based questions are off-topic here

Comment: I've already edited the question. Thanks.